# How to make dragged div delete on drop over div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this program that make draggable `<div></div>'s` dynamically. I'm trying to make any draggable `<div></div>` be deleted when it dropped over the id="trash" `<div></div>`

I tried doing something like this, but it just deletes the trash div:

```
      $(function() {
    
    var trash = document.getElementById('trash');

    $(trash).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) { 
             $(this).remove("div");
      }
    });
  });
```

I was trying to identify the `<div></div>` being dropped but wasn't sure how to go about it.

Here is my full code:

```js
function addElement () { 
  
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  
  // create a new div element and give it a unique id
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.id = 'temp'

  // and give it some content
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text); 
  
  // add the text node to the newly created div
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);  

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 

  $(function() {
    
    var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    $(div).draggable();
    $("#temp").draggable();

    $(td).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) { 
          $( this )
          .addClass("div")
            .html( text );
              $("div").draggable();

          $( "#temp" ).remove();
      }
    });
  });


  document.getElementById("input").value = " ";



$(function () {
    $("td").dblclick(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var currentEle = $(this);
        var value = $(this).html();
        updateVal(currentEle, value);
    });
});

function updateVal(currentEle, value) {
    $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="' + text + '" />');
    $(".thVal").focus();
    $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function () {
            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
    });
}

}


var div = document.getElementsByClassName('div');

  $( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<button>Delete</button>" ) ).attr('id', 'melement');


    function dump() {
      $(this).parent().html("").removeClass("div");
    }
    
    $( "#melement button" ).on( "click", dump );
    }, function() {
      $( this ).find( "button" ).last().remove();
    }
  );


  $(function() {
    
    var trash = document.getElementById('trash');

    $(trash).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) { 
             $(this).remove("div");
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

.blank {

}


.div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

td{
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 20px ;
  width: 200px;
}

.div:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.trash {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Input text:</h1>
    <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="input">
    <button onclick="addElement()" >input</button> 


<div id="trash" class="trash">Trash Can</div>

     <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ui.draggable[i].remove()` you can get the element being dragged within that functionby using a for loop. Loop through the ui.draggable object and use the incremented variable in the for loop `i` as a key to target the selected element being dragged.

***EDIT:*** *Added a for loop to loop through ui.draggable items in order to target the element that is being dragged when more than one draggable item has been added. Also I would change your function that adds the ID to the created div that holds the text item created to concatenate a number to the ID, otherwise you will have identical IDs when more than one text item is added.*

```js
$(function() {
  var trash = document.getElementById('trash');
  $(trash).droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      for (let i = 0; i < ui.draggable.length; i++) {
        ui.draggable[i].remove();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

In your questionn you are removing the event with `$(this)` which is the trash can.

```js
function addElement() {

  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;

  // create a new div element and give it a unique id
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.id = 'temp'

  // and give it some content
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text);

  // add the text node to the newly created div
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);

  $(function() {

    var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    $(div).draggable();
    $("#temp").draggable();

    $(td).droppable({
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this)
          .addClass("div")
          .html(text);
        $("div").draggable();

        $("#temp").remove();
      }
    });
  });


  document.getElementById("input").value = " ";



  $(function() {
    $("td").dblclick(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      var currentEle = $(this);
      var value = $(this).html();
      updateVal(currentEle, value);
    });
  });

  function updateVal(currentEle, value) {
    $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="' + text + '" />');
    $(".thVal").focus();
    $(".thVal").keyup(function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
      }
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
      $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
    });
  }

}


var div = document.getElementsByClassName('div');

$("td").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).append($("<button>Delete</button>")).attr('id', 'melement');


    function dump() {
      $(this).parent().html("").removeClass("div");
    }

    $("#melement button").on("click", dump);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find("button").last().remove();
  }
);


$(function() {
  var trash = document.getElementById('trash');
  $(trash).droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      for (let i = 0; i < ui.draggable.length; i++) {
        ui.draggable[i].remove();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

.blank {}

.div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

.div:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.trash {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Input text:</h1>
  <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="input">
  <button onclick="addElement()">input</button>


  <div id="trash" class="trash">Trash Can</div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This can potentially fail when you create two (or more) elements, both with the same id - this is exactly the current case. Each element is created with id temp'.

Comment: Added a for loop to loop through ui items

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the element you want to delete.
This can be taken from the `event` parameter you're passing in the `droppable` callback.

```
$(trash).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) { 
       $(event.toElement).remove();
  }
 });`
```

`event.toElement` gets the element you're dropping. Then you just can call `remove` on it.